# Saving Cells from One Worksheet to a worksheet in a diff workbook -- having it save without prompt

Tags: excel, vba, save, xlsx

Quick question.

I have this macro here, which has the functionality I Need (saves 2 cells from one worksheet in a workbook, to a worksheet in a different workbook.

The only issue I have is it keeps prompting for saving the file, and won't let me actually save it.

Any thoughts on what snippet of code I need to add to resolve?  It appears it's opening the file as readonly, and maybe that's the issue?

```
Sub Test()
Dim x As Workbook
Dim y As Workbook
Dim vals As Variant

'## Open both workbooks first:
Set x = Workbooks.Open("C:/File.xlsx")
Set y = ThisWorkbook

'Store the value in a variable:
vals = y.Sheets("List").Range("B3:B4").Value

'Use the variable to assign a value to the other file/sheet:
x.Sheets("P1").Range("A1:A2").Value = vals

'Close x:
x.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: `x.Close SaveChanges:=True`?

Comment: Hmm, I tried that and for some reason it prompts to save a different file name as "copy of Test"  , so still doesn't autosave it.  Slightly confused why it's doing that.

Comment: _It appears it's opening the file as readonly, and maybe that's the issue?_ Yes, that is the issue.

Comment: try something like ```x.SaveAs fileName:='File.xlsx", FileFormat:=52, CreateBackup:=False, AccessMode:=xlExclusive, _
    ConflictResolution:=Excel.XlSaveConflictResolution.xlLocalSessionChanges```     you could also try turning off display alerts at the beginning of the sub.

Comment: Adding that right above End Sub gives me a syntax error on it.  Assuming that more or less eliminates the readonly issue if the syntax is right?

Comment: Let me post complete code below. What that does is ```Save As``` the file name and overwrites the existing file without an alert message.

Comment: @Codegameproper, if that works for you too, please mark it as useful/correct answer. I could use the reputation points. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tested this and it works without an alert message. Just edit the file path in the open and save statements

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()
Dim x As Workbook
Dim y As Workbook
Dim vals As Variant

'## Open both workbooks first:
Set x = Workbooks.Open("C:\Test.xlsx")
Set y = ThisWorkbook

'Store the value in a variable:
vals = y.Sheets("List").Range("B3:B4").Value

'Use the variable to assign a value to the other file/sheet:
x.Sheets("P1").Range("A1:A2").Value = vals

'Turns off Alerts
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

'Saves file with changes
x.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Test.xlsx", FileFormat:=51, CreateBackup:=False, AccessMode:=xlExclusive, _
ConflictResolution:=Excel.XlSaveConflictResolution.xlLocalSessionChanges

'Close x:
x.Close

'turns alerts back on
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```